# My van steering wheel shakes

Tags: toyota, wheels, steering, shaking

I have a 1983 Toyota Hiace LH50 van.

When I speed it up to 60-65 kph the steering wheel begins to shake and when I lower the speed to 50kph nothing.
All I have to do to avoid the shaking is maintain a speed of 50kph or lower.

I have replaced brand new tires and I have had the wheels aligned but it still shakes.

The balance bar mount has broken - could this be the cause?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is that broken mount - your chassis will be flexing, especially in a 30 year old van, so get that fixed first.

There could be various other causes as well (bearings, suspension arms, stub axles etc) but you need to get to a solid platform first before trying to diagnose any further.